# Store data Array from code behind into javascript in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, arraylist

I have code like this :

```
 Dim ListMyDate = New List(Of MyDate)()

        Dim cek As Date = "2017/10/15","2017/10/16"
        ListMyDate.Add(New MyDate() With {.ShowDate = cek})

    allRecords = ListMyDate.ToArray()

    For Each obj As MyDate In ListMyDate
        Response.Write(obj.ShowDate.ToString() + ",")
    Next
```

This code work for me, but I want store data result from my array to javascript.

Comment: Great. What have you tried?

Comment: 1. Just use Response.Write to write javascript.  2. Write some JSON...